# Books that talk about both Jordan decomposition of a function, and of a signed measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Do you know about any books in real analysis/measure theory that talk about both the jordan decomposition of a function, and the jordan decomposition of a signed measure, and their connection?(The connection beeing the connection of the measures generated by the jordan composition of the function, and the jordan decomposition of the signed measure generated by the function, and proofs of the connection.)

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Gerald Folland's "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications."